# How can I enable inline ManyToManyFields on my Django admin site?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Let's say I have Books and Author models.

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = CharField(max_length=250)
    authors = ManyToManyField(Author)
```

I want each Book to have multiple Authors, and on the Django admin site I want to be able to add multiple new authors to a book from its Edit page, in one go. I don't need to add Books to authors.

Is this possible? If so, what's the best and / or easiest way of accomplishing it?

Answer (score 32):

It is quite simple to do what you want, If I am getting you correctly:

You should create an admin.py file inside your apps directory and then write the following code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myapps.models import Author, Book

class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     model= Book
     filter_horizontal = ('authors',) #If you don't specify this, you will get a multiple select widget.

admin.site.register(Author)
admin.site.register(Book, BookAdmin)
```

Comment: If you use the above code in admin.py, you will get a tiny "+" button next to filtered-selector. You can click it and add "new authors", one at a time which will go to filtered side by themselves on addition.

Comment: Your solution is the good one but you have an error in it: `class Book` should be `class BookAdmin`. Also, you don't need to specify the model (`model= Book`).

Comment: @Etienne:
Explicit is better than implicit.
~Zen of Python - Tim Peters (PEP 20)  
sorry about missing on BookAdmin. Corrected.

Comment: @Prateek: Simple is better than complex. Better remove model= Book, because it is unnecessary and causes confusion.

Comment: Django doesn't add form fields for many-to-many model fields, if intermidiary model was defined [explicitly](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.0.2/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L245).

Answer (score 29):

Try this:

```
class AuthorInline(admin.TabularInline):

    model = Book.authors.through
    verbose_name = u"Author"
    verbose_name_plural = u"Authors"


class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    exclude = ("authors", )
    inlines = (
       AuthorInline,
    )
```

You might need to add `raw_id_fields = ("author", )` to `AuthorInline` if you have many authors.

Comment: Thank you, too! I'm so happy to find this old answer. If you're still around could you please explain how `raw_id_fields` works with **"author"**? Field with that name isn't declared in none of the models. To which value does it refer?

Comment: I have some hunch, the **"author"** would get the value from the column **author_id** in the table for `Book.authors.through` which would be something like `app_book_authors` (`app` stands here for the app label).

Comment: [`raw_id_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields) allows you to specify ids in a text field, instead of choosing related records with a select element. Makes sense when you've got a lot of records in related table. To improve performance.

Answer (score 8):

Well, check out the [Django docs on many to many usage with inlines](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models).