# Django: ManyToMany association not working

Tags: django, django-models

models.py

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Image(models.Model):
    in_gallery = models.ManyToManyField(Gallery,  blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class ImageInGallery (models.Model):
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image,  blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery,  blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

[Click to view the screenshot of my admin page of adding a Gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6yZt.png)

[Click to view the screenshot of my admin page of adding an Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YboM4.png)

Have a look at the screen shot....
(ignore the fields that I didn't show in models.py code for simplicity) See the difference I have in admin page of adding a `Gallery` and `Image`..... **I cannot add image to Gallery**

How to fix this?

Comment: Hint: the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships) show that you don't need the model `ImageInGallery` if you don't use the [`through` attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) on the `ManyToManyField`.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Show us the error or describe it a bit clearer.

Comment: how to use through attribute? I have uploaded some screenshots, hope its clear enough

Comment: You probably are looking for an [inline manytomanyfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884937/how-can-i-enable-inline-manytomanyfields-on-my-django-admin-site) for your admin; that question has some pointers on how to achive that.

Answer (score 0):

what's the purpose of ImageInGallery ?

You have to use `through` argument.

Since you define `ManyToManyField` in `Image` you already have a bilateral relation.

If you want all galleries related to an `image1` instance of `Image` you can do a :

```
image1.galleries.all()
```

If you want images related to `gallery1` instance of `Gallery`, you can do :

```
galleries.image_set.all()
```

[In documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/), your Gallery is 'Publication' and Image is 'Article'.